# Data gone after refresh page

Tags: angular

My data is gone after refresh page.

Scenario:

LucrariComponent (Data shown) -> refresh page -> LucrariComponent (No data shown)

The data only shown at the first load, but then it's gone whenever I change the page or refresh the page.

On console log i receive the data from the api in page - but i only get this:
[image]

Using a template with routes.

HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let lucrare of lucrari">
          <td>
            <a href="#" class="text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary fs-6">
              {{ lucrare.projectNumber }}
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a
              href="#"
              class="text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary d-block mb-1 fs-6 region"
            >
            {{ lucrare.projectRegion }}
            </a>
            <span class="text-muted fw-bold text-muted d-block fs-7"
              >{{ lucrare.addressLine }}</span
            >
          </td>
</tr>
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-lucrari',
  templateUrl: './lista-lucrari.component.html',
})
export class ListaLucrariComponent implements OnInit{
  lucrari:any;

  constructor(private service:PostService) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLucrari()
  };

  getLucrari(): void {
    this.lucrari = [];
    this.service.getLucrari().subscribe(response => {
      this.lucrari = response;
      console.log(this.lucrari);
    });

  }
}
```

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthService} from "../modules/auth";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PostService {
  private url = 'api-url';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) { }

  getLucrari(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url, { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.currentUserValue})});
  }

}
```

It's my first angular project - so I may mess up easy things. Thanks for understanding.

I've tried almost all solutions that i could find. Most likely i don't search for the right thing, since i'm new to angular.

Comment: Data is coming in the API after refresh?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik Yes, new console log with data everytime i change page / refresh

Comment: Can you try ctrl+f5 to refresh completely the page

Comment: yes, same - is not displaying data - but in console log that data is there.

Comment: Have you changed the ChangeDetection strategy in any of the parent components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In your *ListaLucrariComponent* component, change your constructor to

`constructor(private service:PostService,  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}`

Then, modify your *getLucari* method to

```
getLucrari(): void {
    this.lucrari = [];
    this.service.getLucrari().subscribe(response => {
      this.lucrari = response;
      this.cdr.detectChanges()
      console.log(this.lucrari);
    });

  }
```

This should cause **ngFor* to trigger again, and rerun the logic that renders your page.

Comment: Happy to help. In general, *ngFor usually automatically updates the view whenever it detects a change. Sometimes this doesn't happen though, so calling `detectChanges()` will nudge it in the right direction. 

Be aware that there could be a case you call `detectChanges()` and `ngOnChanges()` will fire and you'll have an infinite loop, so it's good to be mindful of what's happening under the hood. 

More info here: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef